# Best place for media mentioned logos and customers' logos

Tags: usability

I was handed a one pager that is already designed. I was asked to insert these two category of logos:

1. Media mentioned logos
2. Customers' logos

The main sections of this site are:

- Why use this product
- What is this product
- How it works
- Success stories
- Contact

Where do you think is the best place to put them?

Comment: "Best" is usually hard to define, but "success stories" sounds like a logical place to me. After all, a happy customer is a success story.

Comment: True, "Best" is a Tough one :) But should the tow sets of logos go together on success stories, or should the 'media review' logos should go somewhere else?

Comment: I would put it in the same sections for the reasons @RumiP. mentioned, but make a clear distinction in the sets of logos so media that talked about the product aren't seen for customers.

Comment: What is a 'media mentioned logo'?

Answer (score 1):

It is good practice to put company mentioned logos at the bottom of the page, since it is (in a way) a testimonial. In the success area page is a good idea, though I would highly recommend creating a separate page for detailed portfolios of what you've done with the client.

Media mentioned logos should have their own section, below the testimonials section and above the contact section as it's a resource for people to go to for more detailed (and supposedly unbiased) views of your product.

That said, a contact form should always be at the bottom as the CTA. It should have minimal distractions and convey a clear message. I recommend using carousels to display the differnent logos, and using AJAX to display a single quote in big font.